# How to write a mutator method for a class that models a gradebook?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that models a gradebook and I am having trouble with one of the steps needed for a mutator method. so for class Assignment() I have instance variables of name, totalPoints, min grade and max grade, sum of all grades, and a count of all grades. Assignment is used to track grades for a single assignment. I have already set up the explicit constructor and initialized variables but then it asks for a An accrueScore() mutator that takes an explicit parameter of the score to consider. It should update fields according to these rules:

1. If the score is outside the range of 0 through the total points available, do nothing.
2. If it is the first score seen, then it should set the min and max to the score
3. If the new score is higher than all previous grades, then update the max score.
4. If the new score is lower than all previous grades, then update the min score.
5. Add the score into the running sum
6. Update the count of seen scores

This is what I have so far:

```java
    public class Assignment {
       // instance variables
       private String name;
       private int totalPoints;
       private int minScore;
       private int maxScore;
       private int sum;
       private int count;

       // Constructor for objects of class Assignment.

    public Assignment(String inName, int inTotalPoints) {
       // initialise instance variables
       this.name = inName;
       this.totalPoints = inTotalPoints;
       this.minScore = 0;
       this.maxScore = 0;
       this.sum = 0;
       this.count = 0;
     }

   // mutator method to update score fields
   public int accrueScore(int newScore) {
      // put your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252468/discussion-on-question-by-amber-lyda-how-to-write-a-mutator-method-for-a-class-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's implemented below with guiding comments.

```
   // mutator method to update score fields
   public int accrueScore(int newScore) {
      //First point: we expect newScore to fit into an interval
      //I'm not sure that inTotalPoints is the "total points available"
      //We expect, so, if I misunderstood it, correct me
      if ((0 <= newScore) && (newScore <= inTotalPoints)) {
          //Point 2: If count is 0, then it's the first score
          //So we set minScore and maxScore in this case
          if (count == 0) {
              minScore = maxScore = newScore;
          }
          //Point3: Adjust maxScore if the score is greater
          if (newScore > maxScore) {
              maxScore = newScore;
          }
          //Point4: Adjust minScore if the score is lesser
          if (newScore < minScore) {
              minScore = newScore;
          }
          //Point5: Add the score to the sum
          sum += newScore;
          //Point6: Increment the count
          count++;
      }
   }
```